# Azure Data Factory access issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

New to Azure and I was trying to play a bit with Data Factory v2.

Got a free subscription and created a data factory within that subscription, and assigned my user the `Data Factory Contributor` role on the subscription.

My problem is that whenever I try to author a pipeline and I navigate to the data factory web page I keep getting an error "Azure Data Factory  is not accessible".

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Please go to the data factory overview page and try assign the contributor role to the user again.

Comment: Didn’t work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a browser compatibility issues. The Azure Data Factory Web app is supported on Chrome, Edge and IE 11, not supported on brave and safari, because of the difference of browser rendering core and js engine.

Comment: You could always disable the protection on brave, the ADF Web App works on my side with no issue (when the protection is off).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your data factory is in an invalid state. When you click in your Data factory it opens the overview page, check if Status is "Succeeded".